# Is it possible to implement "OK Google" like functionality using Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, voice-recognition

I am trying to build an app like Alex or Google Home, suppose a user says "Hey MyApp", mic should be opened or a function associated with the button should be invoked automatically

I have tried API.ai and Ionic TTS plugins, but not able to find anything to enable native features using voice commands in Ionic.

Comment: have you try Speech Ionic Speech recognition

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it using Ionic Speech recognition [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/speech-recognition)

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-speechrecognition
npm install @ionic-native/speech-recognition
```

add it module

then run

```
import { SpeechRecognition } from '@ionic-native/speech-recognition/ngx';

constructor(private speechRecognition: SpeechRecognition) { }

...



// Check feature available
this.speechRecognition.isRecognitionAvailable()
  .then((available: boolean) => console.log(available))

// Start the recognition process
this.speechRecognition.startListening(options)
  .subscribe(
    (matches: string[]) => console.log(matches),
    (onerror) => console.log('error:', onerror)
  )

// Stop the recognition process (iOS only)
this.speechRecognition.stopListening()

// Get the list of supported languages
this.speechRecognition.getSupportedLanguages()
  .then(
    (languages: string[]) => console.log(languages),
    (error) => console.log(error)
  )

// Check permission
this.speechRecognition.hasPermission()
  .then((hasPermission: boolean) => console.log(hasPermission))

// Request permissions
this.speechRecognition.requestPermission()
  .then(
    () => console.log('Granted'),
    () => console.log('Denied')
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, this plugin also required some button click to enable the mic. Is there any way to trigger an event on voice command. I am building an app to enable blind folks to answer the questions using voice commands.

Comment: Hello @VikasSharma, Did you find the solution? I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Call voice recognition function inside constructor & build the app and install.

And then say ok Google open ( your app name)
Google assistant open your app and voice recognition fiction will be automatically trigger.